# Update a third component on focus/click based on the selected values of two other components

Tags: javascript, formio

My form.io panel looks like this [JSON](https://jsonformatter.org/ce359f). I have a panel wherein there are components such as dropdowns & textfields.

I am trying to get a calculated value to a textfield component based on the selected values on two other components. The value should be populated either at the time of getting focus or click event on the textfileld component.

I have tried to use **calculateValue** on the textfield but nothing seems to happen. No errors as well. The component with key *dental* in the link provided above is where you will find the javascript i have tried.

Answer (score 0):

In form.io's calculateValue, you need to be setting value in order to update the field.

```
value=data.param1+data.param2;
```

I've got an example for a text field here that worked for me immediately:

```
{
            "label": "Select + Select1",
            "tableView": true,
            "calculateValue": "value=data.select+data.select1",
            "key": "textText2",
            "type": "textfield",
            "input": true
},
```

You may also be running into issues because of how you're getting your data values. data. is the recommended way to get other data values in calculateValue.

Comment: Thanks. But like i mentioned in my question what i would like to do is a conditional calculation, which in my case is as follows. Should value *A* be selected in dropdown *D1* and value *B* be selected in dropdown *D2* I would like the textfield to show 8 i.e. 3+5. Should other values be selected in the two dropdowns I want another calculation to shown in the textfield. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: @Bisoux Does your dropdown contain numbers? What I posted works when the dropdown options' values are set to a number. It seems like the question you're asking might not be form.io specific. You may just need to map your data values to the numbers when calculating the value.

Comment: the two dropdowns are not numbers. Not sure what you mean by map them. I tried using a javascript *if...then*. the option i see is using some sort of event listener that fires everytime when either of the dropdown changes which i tried  but that does not work as well.

Comment: like, if the selection is A, set value1 to 3, and if it's B, set value1 to 8. 
or just make a dictionary:
var dict={
 "option one": 27,
 "option two": 36
}

console.log(dict["option one"]+2); //29